# Php how to insert update multiple selected records under multiple categories?

Tags: php, codeigniter

have 3 static categories and tasks under these categories.If user have selected any tasks previously then these tasks are coming alreday selected as chekboxes. Now on update view 3 categories are listed with tasks that are alreday selected and user can uncheck from that tasks and can add any other task. Now i have to remove the tasks that are unchecked, insert new checked tasks and update which are alreday checked. But my code is not working properly.Currently i am trying to go into correct condition.

One point tasks values are not commar seperated into table.multiple entries are inserting for with categroy.

$Tasklist = $this->TaskModel->getAllTaskList(); // to get all tasks from tasks table

```
foreach($Tasklist['data'] as $val)
{
    
    $TaskId[]= $val['task_id'];
        
}

$tasklistVal = $inputs_ary['selected_task_val']; // selected tasks on update form

if(array_filter($tasklistVal)!=[])
{
    
    foreach($tasklistVal as $value)
    {
        
        if(in_array($value, $TaskId))
        {
            echo "update";
            
        }else{

            echo "insert delete";
        }   
        
        
        
    }   
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the "insert_batch" function in codeigniter

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).